# Right-align bar label text to Chart Area in Google Charts

Tags: charts, google-visualization

I'd like to be able to have the bar label text right aligned to the chart area, so that all the labels line up at the 400K gridline?

Here's a JSFiddle showing what I have so far.
https://jsfiddle.net/67u052kL/1/

This is the part that creates the DataView; columns 1 and 3 have the labels I'd like to change the position of:

```
var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
view.setColumns([
    0,
    1,{
        calc: 'stringify',
        sourceColumn: 1,
        type: 'string',
        role: 'annotation'},
    2,
    3,{
        calc: 'stringify',
        sourceColumn: 3,
        type: 'string',
        role: 'annotation' }
    ]);
```

Comment: hey @Philip, just saw this question. do you still need help? this one is a little more difficult. Google does not provide any method for aligning annotations. But we can manually move the labels on the chart's ready event. But I'm pretty sure the chart will reset the alignment on any interactivity, so we would need to use a `MutationObserver` to keep them in place.